# Stylesheets aren't being applied PHP- Warning: PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, css, apache, php-5.6

I'm not sure if anyone has come across this issue. I'm hosting my site with Host Gator and just recently my stylesheet(s) aren't being applied to my  index.php files. It started with working with one php file that was on the root (public_html), but when I aded a php file in another directory, it didn't apply the stylesheet. So I added the stylesheet code beween the  and it seemed to work, but later it stopped. Of course, I called Host Gator and they couldn't come up with a way to resolve the issue, but managed to look at the error logs that were recorded.  Here is just a few errors being repeatedly recorded:

> [18-Sep-2017 16:51:16 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   SourceGuardian: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with
>   module API=20100525 PHP    compiled with module API=20131226

(two different versions of PHP?)

> [18-Sep-2017 17:00:55 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   imagick: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with module
>   API=20100525 PHP    compiled with module API=20131226 These options
>   need to match  in Unknown on line 0

I read in an article that SourceGuardian isn't an open source application and you can't figure out what is going on with it, so therefore it would be best to disable it, but Host Gator would have to do that on their end.

Also the error is complaining about certain files being missing which, even after uploading them, it still wasn't doing anything to solve the issus. All files are in their proper directory and I'm pointing everything to the correct folders.

Here is another error log sent to me:

> [Fri Sep 22 23:53:48 2017] [error] [client 107.77.241.1] File does not
>   exist: /home1/origme/public_html/facebook-unpublished-post-dark/css,
>   referer:  [Fri Sep 22 23:53:48 2017] [error] [client 107.77.241.1]
>   File does not exist:
>   /home1/origme/public_html/facebook-unpublished-post-dark/css, referer:
>   http://www.myhustleconnection.com/facebook-unpublished-post-dark/ [Fri
>   Sep 22 23:54:48 2017] [error] [client 192.185.1.20] File does not
>   exist:  [Fri Sep 22 23:54:48 2017] [error] [client 192.185.1.20] File
>   does not exist: /home1/origme/public_html/css/style-medium.css

Now I'm confused as why it would be wanting the file CSS in a directery it's not meant to be in. All files it requested had been uploaded again and still not resolving the issue. Pages look out of alignment without the stylesheets being applied.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">` is the correct path. 
`<?php ('../includes/header.php'); ?>` is pointing to the correct directory.

At one time the server reverted back to PHP 5.4 when I ran the info.php config file.

`.htaccess` file:
DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html

## BEGIN custom php.ini PHP56

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /home1/origme/public_html
</IfModule>
```

.HTACCESS configuration

```
#USE PHP 56 AS DEFAULT
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
# END custom php.ini
```

Am I missing something in the `.htaccess` config file or the `php.ini` file?

Configuration File (php.ini) Path   `/opt/php56/lib` (is correct)

Thanks!

Comment: The css issues from the log files are certainly explainable by how your page creates references to them. You would need to supply code for that, best examples of the final html markup you send out.

Comment: The module issues with different API versions _probably_ are caused by upgrade processes on the server side. Note that your page is not served by a single system if you use a hosting service provider, but by an army of systems. They are not always completely in sync. That will only be relevant if an issue persists.

Comment: @arkascha I finally found out what was going on! I had not set the relative paths in my directory, so I used '($_SERVER ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/path/to/my/includes/' and just put my includes in the root. I ended up updating to PHP 7, but that wasn't the problem. The funny thing is having to make sure my css folder, image folder, etc are in the same directory. I tested this by installing xampp and running it on my end. I also found where the memory issue was coming from. I had put a space between my PHP code and the <html> tag whiched caused PHP to flip out.

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I said that this is a question of how you construct you references. If you had posted examples of such references (parts of your HTML markup) as I asked we would have been able to help. Great that you found the solution, have fun with your project!